# Android WebView Proxy Settings

Tags: java, android, proxy

Is there currently a way to set the WebView proxy settings with an Android application, using the Android sdk?

Comment: What you intended to achieve? Do you what to load into a webview in your app that needs proxy settings so the webview can load your url? If so I'm having the same problem. How do you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API.");

    Context appContext = webView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", port + "");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", host);
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", port + "");
    try {
        Field loadedApkField = appContext.getClass().getField("mLoadedApk");
        loadedApkField.setAccessible(true);
        Object loadedApk = loadedApkField.get(appContext);
        Class loadedApkCls = Class.forName("android.app.LoadedApk");
        Field receiversField = loadedApkCls.getDeclaredField("mReceivers");
        receiversField.setAccessible(true);
        ArrayMap receivers = (ArrayMap) receiversField.get(loadedApk);
        for (Object receiverMap : receivers.values()) {
            for (Object rec : ((ArrayMap) receiverMap).keySet()) {
                Class clazz = rec.getClass();
                if (clazz.getName().contains("ProxyChangeListener")) {
                    Method onReceiveMethod = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("onReceive", Context.class, Intent.class);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Proxy.PROXY_CHANGE_ACTION);

                    onReceiveMethod.invoke(rec, appContext, intent);
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Setting proxy with >= 4.4 API successful!");
        return true;
```

it works well for Andriod 7.1 in emulator